# if wordpress title is duplicate add post ID to title

Tags: wordpress, function

I want a code to check when post create if post title is duplicate (already exists) add post ID to the title.
I have a piece of code for adding post id to title and it works fine in php 5.6 above

```
add_filter('title_save_pre','auto_generate_post_title');
function auto_generate_post_title($title) {
   global $post;
   if (isset($post->ID)) {
      if (empty($_POST['post_title']) && 'post' == get_post_type($post->ID)){
         // get the current post ID number
         $id = get_the_ID();
         // add ID number with order strong
         $title = $title .' - ' .$id;} }
   return $title; 
}
```

but I need an extra condition to check if the post title already exists does that.

let's say I have a post with this title "the best sandwich" and when I want to create a new post with the exact title again "the best sandwich" and post id is 216, the new title should be: "the best sandwich - 216"

Comment: Hi.  Can you be a little more specific with your question?  It's a little confusing with the wording. Can you give an example of what should happen, with real titles to illustrate what you expect for results?

Comment: @HowardE let's say I have a post with this title "the best sandwich" and when I want to create a new post with the exact title again "the best sandwich" and post id is 216, the new title should be: "the best sandwich - 216"

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve all posts with the title using this:

```
$numberOfPostsWithThisTitle = count(get_posts([ "post_type" => "post", "s" => $title] );
```

Answer (score 0):

Set a variable with the title name, in this case I get on POST the following which is the title I want to check:

```
$_POST['portfolioTitle']
```

Then within a query for all your post you do

```
if ( get_page_by_title( $_POST['portfolioTitle'] ) === null ) {
```

Answer (score 0):

This will check for existing posts, and only append the post id at the end if the title is published.

```php
add_filter('title_save_pre','he_auto_generate_post_title');
function he_auto_generate_post_title($title) {
   global $post, $wpdb;  

    if (isset($post->ID) && $post->post_type == 'post'){
        // create array from the title
        $new_title = explode('-', $post->post_title);
        //query database to find all published posts with same title in beginning.  
        $existing_titles = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT ID, post_title FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts WHERE post_title LIKE '{$title}%' and post_status = 'publish'");
        foreach ($existing_titles as $existing_title){
            // loop through results and find a match
            $check = explode('-', $existing_title->post_title);
            if ($check[0] == $title) {
                // add ID number with order strong
                $title = $new_title[0] .' - ' .$post->ID;
            }
        }
    } 
   return $title; 
}
```

Comment: thanks @Howars E but this code adds post ID in every title regardless of searching for an existing title

Comment: It shouldn't... I tested it.

Comment: unfortunately, it adds post ID in every new post I publish as you can see in the photo. I use wordpress 5.3.2 https://imgur.com/51inrXF

Comment: This is what I see when testing with the updated answer. https://imgur.com/tkS177g wordpress 5.3.2 PHP 7.3